# Asymptote default renderer problem after upgrading to TeX Live 2013

Tags: texlive, 3d, asymptote

I just upgraded my TeX Live installation on Ubuntu 64-bit from 2012 to 2013. After the upgrade, when I tried to render some simple 3D drawings I was not getting the default rendering window to come up. So from the Asymptote manual I added the following lines:

```
import settings;
outformat="";
render=-1;
```

I get the following error:

```
$ asy -V 3test.asy
 /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/asymptote/three.asy: 2906.13: runtime: to support onscreen rendering, please install glut library, run ./configure, and recompile
```

In TeX Live 2012, even without the suggested configuration options, a command such as the one used above would go right into the OpenGL renderer.

Any suggestions as to what is going on?  I am thinking that perhaps the Asymptote that is compiled into TeX Live 2013 is compiled without the glut libraries?  Do I need to compile Asymptote directly from source?

Comment: For what it's worth, I have not had any trouble with Asymptote using MacTeX 2013 (the packaging of TeX Live 2013 for mac).

Answer (score 1):

### Assumption

I guess that you installed "vanilla" TeX Live 2013 from CTAN as explained on the following question [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

For a next time tell also what version of Ubuntu you installed - e.g. Ubuntu 12.04 Longtime-support.

### Requirement of OpenGL/Glut

Check what packages you installed already. I had to install the package `freeglut3-dev`:

```
$ apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```